# Concatenate "changes" output in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a "problem" with a vbscript. I check if a cd is loaded with this piece of code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Computer = "."
Set OutFile = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Const ForAppending = 2
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set WMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & Computer & "\root\cimv2")
Set Items = WMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_CDROMDrive WHERE DRIVE = 'F:'",,48)
For Each SubItems in Items
WScript.Echo "DRIVE: "&SubItems.MediaLoaded
Next
```

It returns "DRIVE: False"

But if I change the line that prints the output for:

```
WScript.Echo SubItems.MediaLoaded
```

Returns -1

Someone knows how I could get "DRIVE:-1" ?

I solved with WScript.Echo "DRIVE: "&cint(SubItems.MediaLoaded) thanks to madzone

Comment: WScript.Echo "DRIVE: " & str(SubItems.MediaLoaded)

Comment: Thank you for the response, it didn't help, but it gives me some clues to solve it. I do it with cint(SubItems.MediaLoaded)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good in English and I think Ekkehard Horner explanations is better than mine. What I know is that string concatenation turn `Boolean` data type in their literal form.

```
WScript.Echo "" & False, 0, False  '>> False 0 0
WScript.Echo "" & True, -1, True   '>> True -1 -1
WScript.Echo 0 = False, 0 = True   '>> -1 0
WScript.Echo -1 = False, -1 = True '>> 0 -1
```

Comment: correct/+1, but I'd prefer '& displays Booleans in their literal form' over 'turns'. Nothing is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CInt function to convert the string back to an integer.

```
WScript.Echo "Drive: " & CInt(SubItems.MediaLoaded)
```

Comment: There is no string involved: -0.49

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), .MediaLoaded's type is boolean

> MediaLoaded
>
> ```
> Data type: boolean
> Access type: Read-only
>
> If True, a CD-ROM is in the drive.
> ```

The concatenation operator & handles VBScript's (sub) types correctly:

```
>> bTrue = True
>> bFalse = False
>> n0 = 0
>> nM1 = -1
>> WScript.Echo "&" & bTrue & bFalse & n0 & nM1
>>
&TrueFalse0-1
```

The internal stringifier component of WScript.Echo does not:

```
>> WScript.Echo ".Echo ,", bTrue, bFalse, n0, nM1
>>
.Echo , -1 0 0 -1
```

Probably the & operator calls CStr() internally:

```
>> WScript.Echo "CStr() ,", CStr(bTrue), CStr(bFalse), CStr(n0), CStr(nM1)
>>
CStr() , True False 0 -1
```

The Join function is industrious too:

```
>> WScript.Echo "Join", Join(Array(bTrue, bFalse, n0, nM1))
>>
Join True False 0 -1
```

Of course you are entitled to have your output look like

```
DRIVE: 0
DRIVE: -1
```

instead of:

```
MediaLoaded: False
MediaLoaded: True
```

but it's not fair to accuse the hardworking & of changing anything.